# How can I import two or more packages in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-snippets, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I want to import the following packages with snippets in jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import yfinance as yf
```

I tried to add my sub_menu in snippets, but I couldn't!
Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: Create an [mcve]

Comment: More info needed: what error are you getting?

Comment: Actually I want to import these packages in cell just by one clic!

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper function can be used to keep things clean.

```
def import_packages():
    global pd, np    # Make the names pd & np global
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
```

And in the main notebook:

```
import utils
utils.import_packages()
utils.pd.DataFrame()
```